# Can a Warlock have a bonded pact weapon and still create other pact weapons

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, warlock

The Warlock can bond with a magical weapon to have it counted as a Pact weapon, which when not in use is shunted into an extra-dimensional pocket for retrieval at a later time. The regular pact weapon is just created out of nowhere and can take any (conventional) form.

**Does this mean that a Warlock can have a bonded weapon stowed away but still create a different pact weapon if it would suit the situation better?**

As an example: could you have a magical dagger stored in the pocket dimension, but summon it as a warhammer for fighting an enemy vulnerable to bludgeoning damage?

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! However, you should consider waiting a bit more before you accept an answer. This helps ensure that all users have gotten a chance to contribute with their answers and vote on the existing ones. When you accept an answer you discourage users from contributing potentially better answers, so we advise you to wait at least a day before you click the check mark. Also, keep in mind that should a better answer come up, you can always change your accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will bare that in mind in future. For the record I accepted off the bat as the PHB provides a conclusive, unambiguous answer to the question that I had misread in previous readings

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon, every time you create your pact weapon thereafter your "bonded" weapon will appear.

> **Pact of the Blade** (PHB p. 107-108)
>
> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon by performing a special ritual while you hold the weapon.
> You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a short rest.
> You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and *it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter*.

---

This is also addressed in the [April 2016 official rules answers](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/rules-answers-april-2016):

> **If a warlock uses Pact of the Blade to bond with a magic weapon, does that weapon have to be a melee weapon, and can the warlock change the weapon’s form?**
>
> You can also use Pact of the Blade to bond with a magic weapon, turning it into your pact weapon. This magic weapon doesn’t have to be a melee weapon, so you could use the feature on a +1 longbow, for instance. Once the bond is formed, the magic weapon appears whenever you call your pact weapon to you, and the intent is that *you can’t change the magic weapon’s form when it appears*.

Comment: Ah I misremembered the wording, I don't have the PHB in front of me, the wording seems pretty conclusive.