# If you make a magic weapon your pact weapon, can you still summon other weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock

The [Pact of the Blade states](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Warlock#toc_9):

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. **You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it.** You are proficient with it while you wield it. This weapon counts as magical for the Purpose of overcoming Resistance and immunity to nonmagical attacks and damage.
> […]
> You can transform one Magic Weapon into your pact weapon by performing a Special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a Short Rest. You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and **it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.** […]

Say I attune to a Flame Tongue (longsword), is that longsword now the only weapon I can summon through this feature? The [Sage Advice](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) makes it clear I cannot reform my Flame Tongue into a javelin, but could I just conjure a regular javelin that is not the Flame Tongue, as I could before I attuned to the magic weapon?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Warlock have a bonded pact weapon and still create other pact weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/80098/can-a-warlock-have-a-bonded-pact-weapon-and-still-create-other-pact-weapons)

Comment: @Jason_c_o While this question asks the same thing, this question is a superior question. It is clearer, with clearer and more numerous answers. Voting to leave open and close the older question.

Comment: @ValhallaGH I just went by date but you're right: this is the way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### No.

This is a case of *specific beats general*. Generally, when you create a pact weapon, this is the rule:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this melee weapon takes each time you create it.

The feature goes on to create an exception to this rule, which is pretty unambiguous:

> You can transform one Magic Weapon into your pact weapon by performing a Special ritual while you hold the weapon. You perform the ritual over the course of 1 hour, which can be done during a Short Rest. You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.

The magic weapon is what appears whenever you would be creating a pact weapon.

Answer (score -2):

When is says

> it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.

it never specifies that the weapon you want to create doesn't **appear as well**, so you could say, RAW, you get the flametongue, *and* the javelin